# How do I get the total of table data with a particular class? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following table:

```
<table class="table questions">
    <tr>
        <td class="someClass">Some data</td>
        <td class="someOtherclass">Some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="someOtherClass">Some data</td>
        <td class="someOtherclass">Some data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="someOtherClass">Some data</td>
        <td class="someClass">Some data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How would I get the total of table data where they had the class value of someClass? e.g. for this table the total would be two.

Comment: You mean the arithmetical sum of cell contents?

Comment: When you say total of table data, do you mean number of rows? or do you actually need to calculate something with `Some data`

Answer (score 3):

Just use .length to find out how many there are

```
$('.questions .someClass').length // will return 2 since there are 2 rows
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. It was really hard to word the question.

Comment: Yeah.. At first I didn't understand it but when you gave the example that `.someClass` should be 2.. I knew you were talking about the element count :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to count the number for elements within a table with `.someClass`

```
$('.someClass', '.questions').length
```

or

```
$('.questions').find('.someClass').length //faster
```

Comment: Using the context selector is slower.

Comment: That's I really don't understand. What's the point in using context part if single CSS selector does the job many times faster.

Comment: @epascarello See updated answer and it is not really going to affect the performance unless it works on thousands of records.

Comment: @VisioN Using context with an assumption that he may have another table with same class or any other element in the document with `.someClass`.

Comment: @Vega The second option is technically ***absolutely*** the same as the first. See jQuery code.

Comment: @VisioN The second option was response to [epascarello](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511711/how-do-i-get-the-total-of-table-data-with-a-particular-class-jquery/14511744#comment20230248_14511744)